# Padding not being applied to element inside container element?

Tags: html, css, format, margin, padding

**Requirements**

I'm essentially trying to replicate the webpage output for this [assignment](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse154/16wi/homework/2/spec.pdf). Pictures used in webpage are [here](https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/). That's basically my ultimate goal in all of this, getting this webpage as close to the desired output as possible.

All of the style must be implemented in CSS. The only HTML tags I can use are organizational ones.

**Problem**

The formatting and spacing with the webpage that I'm trying to create and replicate is unexpectedly wrong.

Each of the text bubbles is supposed to be separated by 20pts of vertical distance. This is something I've attempted to implement in CSS like so:

```
.reviewer-text {
    padding-bottom: 20pt;
}
```

This, however, doesn't work. Almost all the text-bubbles are staggered to a position where they shouldn't be.

If you see the single-line text bubble written by the reviewer Jay Sherman, the vertical distance is smaller and the icon in the text-bubble isn't centered in the way that the other logo images are.

Upon inspecting the element with Firebug, I noticed that the padding is applied only to the text. I don't know how to fix this. I need the padding to apply to the element as a whole. The padding superficially appears to work for the rest of the elements because there are multiple lines of text, but it doesn't, really.

**Main Issues That Need to Be Addressed**

- I need to fix the padding between the reviews.
- I need to fix the images in the reviews so they're oriented properly.
- I need to fix the heading so it's in the same position as the heading in the desired output.

**All of these things need to be fixed without affecting the formatting of the rest of the webpage. The ultimate goal is to keep it as close to the desired output as possible.**

[Current Output](http://oi65.tinypic.com/2zyykbs.jpg)

[Desired Output](http://oi65.tinypic.com/333j2ax.jpg)

[Current Output overlayed on Desired Output](http://oi66.tinypic.com/sqpbet.jpg)

^ This should make the differences between the two more immediately obvious.

**Code**

```css
#banner {
 height: 50px;
 background-image: url(https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rancidbannerbg.png);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

#banner img {
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

body {
 background-image: url(https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/moviebg.png);
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 10pt;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

#column-left, #column-right {
 margin-right: 2%;
 width: 47%;
}

#column-left {
 float: left;
 margin-left: 2%;
}

#column-right {
 float: right;
}

#container {
 background-color: #EEEEEE;
 border-radius: 20px;
 box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray;
 margin: auto;
 width: 800px;
}

#date {
 background-color: #A2B964;
 clear: both;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: center;
}

h1, .reviewer-text {
 font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 24pt;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 text-shadow: 3px 3px #999999;
}

#logo {
 background-image: url(https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rottenlargebg.png);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 height: 83px;
 font-size: 48pt;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: red;
}

#logo img {
 vertical-align: bottom;
}

.publication {
 font-style: italic;
}

#reviews {
 width: 550px;
}

.reviewer-info {
 padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.reviewer-info img, .reviewer-text img {
 float: left;
 margin-right: 5px;
}

.reviewer-text {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
 border-radius: 20px;
 padding-top: 8px;
 padding-bottom: 8px;
 padding-left: 8px;
 padding-right: 8px;
}

#general-overview {
 width: 250px;
 background-color: #A2B964;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 float: right;
}

#general-overview dt {
 font-weight: bold;
 margin-top: 10pt;
 padding-left: 10pt;
}

#general-overview dd {
 padding-left: 10pt;
 padding-right: 10pt;
}

#general-overview ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

#validators {
 bottom: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 position: fixed;
 opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>TMNT - Rancid Tomatoes</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link href="movie.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="rotten.gif" />
 
 </head>

 <body>
  <div id = "banner">
   <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rancidbanner.png" alt="Rancid Tomatoes" />
  </div>

  <h1>TMNT (2007)</h1>

  <div id="container">
   <div id="general-overview">
    <div>
     <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/overview.png" alt="general overview" />
    </div>

    <dl>
     <dt>STARRING</dt>
     <dd>Patrick Stewart <br /> Mako <br /> Sarah Michelle Gellar <br /> Kevin Smith</dd>

     <dt>DIRECTOR</dt>
     <dd>Kevin Munroe</dd>

     <dt>RATING</dt>
     <dd>PG</dd>

     <dt>THEATRICAL RELEASE</dt>
     <dd>Mar 23, 2007</dd>

     <dt>MOVIE SYNOPSIS</dt>
     <dd>After the defeat of their old arch nemesis, The Shredder, the Turtles have grown apart as a family.</dd>

     <dt>MPAA RATING</dt>
     <dd>PG, for animated action violence, some scary cartoon images and mild language</dd>

     <dt>RELEASE COMPANY</dt>
     <dd>Warner Bros.</dd>

     <dt>RUNTIME</dt>
     <dd>90 mins</dd>

     <dt>GENRE</dt>
     <dd>Action/Adventure, Comedies, Childrens, Martial Arts, Superheroes, Ninjas, Animated Characters</dd>

     <dt>BOX OFFICE</dt>
     <dd>$54,132,596</dd>

     <dt>LINKS</dt>
     <dd>
      <br />
      <ul>
       <li><a href="http://www.ninjaturtles.com/">The Official TMNT Site</a></li>
       <li><a href="http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/teenage_mutant_ninja_turtles/">RT Review</a></li>
       <li><a href="http://www.rottentomatoes.com/">RT Home</a></li>

      </ul>
     </dd>
    </dl>
   </div>
   
   <div id="reviews"> 
    <div id="logo">
     <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rottenlarge.png" alt="Rotten" />
     33%
    </div>

    <div id="column-left">
     <p class="reviewer-text">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
      <q>Ditching the cheeky, self-aware wink that helped to excuse the concept's inherent corniness, the movie attempts to look polished and 'cool,' but the been-there animation can't compete with the then-cutting-edge puppetry of the 1990 live-action movie.</q>
     </p>
     <p class="reviewer-info">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
      Peter Debruge <br />
      <span class="publication">Variety</span>
     </p>

     <p class="reviewer-text">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/fresh.gif" alt="Fresh" />
      <q>TMNT is a fun, action-filled adventure that will satisfy longtime fans and generate a legion of new ones.</q>
     </p>
     <p class="reviewer-info">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
      Todd Gilchrist <br />
      <span class="publication">IGN Movies</span>
     </p>

     <p class="reviewer-text">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
      <q>It stinks!</q>
     </p>
     <p class="reviewer-info">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
      Jay Sherman (unemployed)
      <br />
     </p>

     <p class="reviewer-text">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
      <q>The rubber suits are gone and they've been redone with fancy computer technology, but that hasn't stopped them from becoming dull.</q>
     </p>
     <p class="reviewer-info">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
      Joshua Tyler <br />
      <span class="publication">CinemaBlend.com</span>
     </p>

     <p class="reviewer-text">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
      <q>This movie sucks because reasons.</q>
     </p>
     <p class="reviewer-info">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
      T. Tally Nobias <br />
      <span class="publication">objectivereviews.com</span>
     </p>
    </div>

    <div id="column-right">
     <p class="reviewer-text">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
      <q>The turtles themselves may look prettier, but are no smarter; torn irreparably from their countercultural roots, our superheroes on the half shell have been firmly co-opted by the industry their creators once sought to spoof.</q>
     </p>
     <p class="reviewer-info">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
      Jeannette Catsoulis <br />
      <span class="publication">New York Times</span>
     </p>

     <p class="reviewer-text">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
      <q>Impersonally animated and arbitrarily plotted, the story appears to have been made up as the filmmakers went along.</q>
     </p>
     <p class="reviewer-info">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
      Ed Gonzalez <br />
      <span class="publication">Slant Magazine</span>
     </p>

     <p class="reviewer-text">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/fresh.gif" alt="Fresh" />
      <q>The striking use of image and motion allows each sequence to leave an impression. It's an accomplished restart to this franchise.</q>
     </p>
     <p class="reviewer-info">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
      Mark Palermo <br />
      <span class="publication">Coast (Halifax, Nova Scotia)</span>
     </p>

     <p class="reviewer-text">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
      <q>The script feels like it was computer generated. This mechanical presentation lacks the cheesy charm of the three live action films.</q>
     </p>
     <p class="reviewer-info">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
      Steve Rhodes <br />
      <span class="publication">Internet Reviews</span>
     </p>

     <p class="reviewer-text">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
      <q>This movie is literally the worst movie ever. I'm not going to explain why. -10000000/10.</q>
     </p>
     <p class="reviewer-info">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
      A. Rheal Kritik <br />
      <span class="publication">Facade Inc.</span>
     </p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <p id="date">(1-10) of 88</p>
  </div>

  <div id="validators">
   <a href="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/validate-html.php"><img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/w3c-html.png" alt="Valid HTML5" /></a><br />
   <a href="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/validate-css.php"><img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/w3c-css.png" alt="Valid CSS" /></a>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `Margin-bottom`

```css
#banner {
 height: 50px;
 background-image: url(https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rancidbannerbg.png);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

#banner img {
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

body {
 background-image: url(https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/moviebg.png);
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 10pt;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

#column-left, #column-right {
 margin-right: 2%;
 width: 47%;
}

#column-left {
 float: left;
 margin-left: 2%;
}

#column-right {
 float: right;
}

#container {
 background-color: #EEEEEE;
 border-radius: 20px;
 box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray;
 margin: auto;
 width: 800px;
}

#date {
 background-color: #A2B964;
 clear: both;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: center;
}

h1, .reviewer-text {
 font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 24pt;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 text-shadow: 3px 3px #999999;
}

#logo {
 background-image: url(https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rottenlargebg.png);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 height: 83px;
 font-size: 48pt;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: red;
}

#logo img {
 vertical-align: bottom;
}

.publication {
 font-style: italic;
}

#reviews {
 width: 550px;
}

.reviewer-info {
 padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.reviewer-info img, .reviewer-text img {
 float: left;
 margin-right: 5px;
}
.reviewer-text::after {
clear: both;
content: "";
display: block;
}
.reviewer-text {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
 border-radius: 20px;
 padding-top: 8px;
 padding-bottom: 8pt;
 padding-left: 8px;
 padding-right: 8px;
margin-bottom:20pt;
}

#general-overview {
 width: 250px;
 background-color: #A2B964;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 float: right;
}

#general-overview dt {
 font-weight: bold;
 margin-top: 10pt;
 padding-left: 10pt;
}

#general-overview dd {
 padding-left: 10pt;
 padding-right: 10pt;
}

#general-overview ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

#validators {
 bottom: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 position: fixed;
 opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>TMNT - Rancid Tomatoes</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link href="movie.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="rotten.gif" />
 
 </head>

 <body>
  <div id = "banner">
   <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rancidbanner.png" alt="Rancid Tomatoes" />
  </div>

  <h1>TMNT (2007)</h1>

  <div id="container">
   <div id="general-overview">
    <div>
     <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/overview.png" alt="general overview" />
    </div>

    <dl>
     <dt>STARRING</dt>
     <dd>Patrick Stewart <br /> Mako <br /> Sarah Michelle Gellar <br /> Kevin Smith</dd>

     <dt>DIRECTOR</dt>
     <dd>Kevin Munroe</dd>

     <dt>RATING</dt>
     <dd>PG</dd>

     <dt>THEATRICAL RELEASE</dt>
     <dd>Mar 23, 2007</dd>

     <dt>MOVIE SYNOPSIS</dt>
     <dd>After the defeat of their old arch nemesis, The Shredder, the Turtles have grown apart as a family.</dd>

     <dt>MPAA RATING</dt>
     <dd>PG, for animated action violence, some scary cartoon images and mild language</dd>

     <dt>RELEASE COMPANY</dt>
     <dd>Warner Bros.</dd>

     <dt>RUNTIME</dt>
     <dd>90 mins</dd>

     <dt>GENRE</dt>
     <dd>Action/Adventure, Comedies, Childrens, Martial Arts, Superheroes, Ninjas, Animated Characters</dd>

     <dt>BOX OFFICE</dt>
     <dd>$54,132,596</dd>

     <dt>LINKS</dt>
     <dd>
      <br />
      <ul>
       <li><a href="http://www.ninjaturtles.com/">The Official TMNT Site</a></li>
       <li><a href="http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/teenage_mutant_ninja_turtles/">RT Review</a></li>
       <li><a href="http://www.rottentomatoes.com/">RT Home</a></li>

      </ul>
     </dd>
    </dl>
   </div>
   
   <div id="reviews"> 
    <div id="logo">
     <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rottenlarge.png" alt="Rotten" />
     33%
    </div>

    <div id="column-left">
     <p class="reviewer-text">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
      <q>Ditching the cheeky, self-aware wink that helped to excuse the concept's inherent corniness, the movie attempts to look polished and 'cool,' but the been-there animation can't compete with the then-cutting-edge puppetry of the 1990 live-action movie.</q>
     </p>
     <p class="reviewer-info">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
      Peter Debruge <br />
      <span class="publication">Variety</span>
     </p>

     <p class="reviewer-text">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/fresh.gif" alt="Fresh" />
      <q>TMNT is a fun, action-filled adventure that will satisfy longtime fans and generate a legion of new ones.</q>
     </p>
     <p class="reviewer-info">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
      Todd Gilchrist <br />
      <span class="publication">IGN Movies</span>
     </p>

     <p class="reviewer-text">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
      <q>It stinks!</q>
     </p>
     <p class="reviewer-info">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
      Jay Sherman (unemployed)
      <br />
     </p>

     <p class="reviewer-text">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
      <q>The rubber suits are gone and they've been redone with fancy computer technology, but that hasn't stopped them from becoming dull.</q>
     </p>
     <p class="reviewer-info">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
      Joshua Tyler <br />
      <span class="publication">CinemaBlend.com</span>
     </p>

     <p class="reviewer-text">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
      <q>This movie sucks because reasons.</q>
     </p>
     <p class="reviewer-info">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
      T. Tally Nobias <br />
      <span class="publication">objectivereviews.com</span>
     </p>
    </div>

    <div id="column-right">
     <p class="reviewer-text">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
      <q>The turtles themselves may look prettier, but are no smarter; torn irreparably from their countercultural roots, our superheroes on the half shell have been firmly co-opted by the industry their creators once sought to spoof.</q>
     </p>
     <p class="reviewer-info">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
      Jeannette Catsoulis <br />
      <span class="publication">New York Times</span>
     </p>

     <p class="reviewer-text">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
      <q>Impersonally animated and arbitrarily plotted, the story appears to have been made up as the filmmakers went along.</q>
     </p>
     <p class="reviewer-info">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
      Ed Gonzalez <br />
      <span class="publication">Slant Magazine</span>
     </p>

     <p class="reviewer-text">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/fresh.gif" alt="Fresh" />
      <q>The striking use of image and motion allows each sequence to leave an impression. It's an accomplished restart to this franchise.</q>
     </p>
     <p class="reviewer-info">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
      Mark Palermo <br />
      <span class="publication">Coast (Halifax, Nova Scotia)</span>
     </p>

     <p class="reviewer-text">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
      <q>The script feels like it was computer generated. This mechanical presentation lacks the cheesy charm of the three live action films.</q>
     </p>
     <p class="reviewer-info">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
      Steve Rhodes <br />
      <span class="publication">Internet Reviews</span>
     </p>

     <p class="reviewer-text">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
      <q>This movie is literally the worst movie ever. I'm not going to explain why. -10000000/10.</q>
     </p>
     <p class="reviewer-info">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
      A. Rheal Kritik <br />
      <span class="publication">Facade Inc.</span>
     </p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <p id="date">(1-10) of 88</p>
  </div>

  <div id="validators">
   <a href="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/validate-html.php"><img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/w3c-html.png" alt="Valid HTML5" /></a><br />
   <a href="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/validate-css.php"><img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/w3c-css.png" alt="Valid CSS" /></a>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that seems to fix the heading. Do you have any ideas for fixing the padding and the logos in the reviews?

Comment: which logo means rotten 33% ?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Rotten 33% is the heading which you fixed. I mean the images in the upper left corner of the reviews. .reviewer-text img

Comment: The green splatter and tomato icons should be 5px separated from the right from the review text and oriented in the center without touching the edges like the desired output picture

Comment: The issue that needs the most fixing is the spacing between the reviews though

Comment: like this way i attach image

Comment: oh, sorry, no. the text should still wrap around the logo.

Comment: the desired output picture in my post should show what it needs to look like

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101367/discussion-between-lalji-tadhani-and-user3450277).

Answer (score 0):

```
.reviewer-text {
    padding-bottom: 20pt;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work because it changes the webpage too drastically from the desired output. :(