# Style that I apply to an element doesn't apply to elements nested inside?

Tags: html, css, margin, element, padding

**Conditions**

I'm essentially trying to replicate the webpage output for this [assignment](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse154/16wi/homework/2/spec.pdf). Pictures used in webpage are [here](https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/). That's basically my ultimate goal in all of this, getting this webpage as close to the [Desired Output](http://oi65.tinypic.com/333j2ax.jpg) as possible. Not just similar, but as close to identical as possible.

This needs to be done in a way that doesn't just superficially reflect the intended output, but is done in the "right" way. For example, I could very well just adjust padding and margin sizes until it looks the way it needs to be, but that wouldn't solve the overarching problem and makes for badly styled code.

This has to be predominantly done with CSS. Only organizational HTML tags can be used and no packages or code can be imported.

**Problem:**

Each review is supposed to be separated by 20pt of vertical distance. This isn't working out for whatever reason.

It might have something to do with the fact that I've got some of my reviews looking like [this](http://oi63.tinypic.com/8zfpte.jpg) when I need them to look like [this](http://i67.tinypic.com/2lnydg9.jpg).

That might have to do with the fact that padding is applying only to the [text](http://i66.tinypic.com/bhlj5w.jpg) when it needs to apply to the review as a [whole](http://oi68.tinypic.com/2zt90lj.jpg).

You can see in the first image that the blue bar, which represents padding, is only under the text and not under the image and the text.

I'm wondering if this has something to do with img elements being inline elements and not block elements? Any advice you have on this would be greatly apprecaited.

**Code:**

[CSS](http://pastebin.com/1XPJ1cQh)

[HTML](http://pastebin.com/5Lhy7Qnr)

Comment: Is this not essentially a duplicate of this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34940238/padding-not-being-applied-to-element-inside-container-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The padding does not work with your images because you have

```
float: left
```

applied to them. If you take that property out, the padding will take the img into account.

On a side note: maybe you should reconsider your html structure. Logically the review text and the reviewer belong together, so they should be enclosed by some parent div element. Just look at the real rotten tomatoes website and how they structure their reviews and let that "inspire" you ;-)

But basically it should be something like this:

```
<div class="review">
  <div class="review_quote"></div>
  <div class="review_source"></div>
</div>
```

Well structured HTML really helps with styling. HTML and CSS go hand in hand, so if your HTML is messy your CSS will be messy and "hacky" too. So first make sure your HTML makes sense (grouping, nesting, etc.) first.

Comment: Thanks! This answer ended up helping me the most.

Comment: Glad I could help ;-)

Answer (score 0):

add this class in your css

```
.reviewer-text::after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well.. your padding in css is refering only to class 'reviewer-info'. Elements with class 'reviewer-text' got their padding set to 8px;

If you want to have result for that block like on the picture apply bottom padding for 'reviewer-text'. Change:

```
.reviewer-text {
   padding: 8px;
}
```

to:

```
.reviewer-text {
   padding: 8px 8px 20px 8px;
}
```

See: https://fiddle.jshell.net/a9xxoz8L/1/